# Is 'must have took' possible in spoken English?

Tags: grammaticality, past-participles

I encountered a sentence a speaker says 'The person must've took down the wrong name.'
 [Watch it from 0:57](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW6SGjhfc60)

is it grammatically correct? or a common mistake?

Comment: It is common to hear people incorrectly using the past tense of a verb, instead of the past participle, after *have* and *had*. Common examples are: *must have ate* and *must have spoke*. Obviously, the error is apparent only when the form of the verb changes between the tenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it would be more correct to say "The person must have taken down the wrong name", but the error is small enough that it would normally be commonly not noticed when used in spoken English. Probably more noticeable in written English, since that tends to be a little more formal than spoken English.